# JDBC接続のエンコーディング設定方法

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, wildfly

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40133/nchar2-nvarchar2%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AB%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8C%96%E3%81%91%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E6%A0%BC%E7%B4%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)に関連します。

[この記事の「(2) JDBC接続のエンコーディングをUTF-8に設定」のところ](http://sakaisusie.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/07/02/001911)に、GlassfishでのJDBC接続のエンコーディング設定方法が説明されています。

WildflyやJBossEAPで、上記設定に相当するものをやりたいのですが、どうやればいいのでしょうか？

【追記】
使用しているDBは、SQLServer, Oracle, PostgreSQLです。
現状、Oracleのみ、SJIS(CP932)外の文字を保存しようとすると、文字化けが発生しています。
アプリケーション（JPA）を介さずに、直接SQLを流す場合、Nプレフィクスをつけていれば文字化けしないので、DB側の問題ではないと推測しています。

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html こちらの説明に properties defaultNChar  というのがあります。これをtrueにセットすると文字化けしますか？

Comment: `myApplication`のところに何を書いたらいいのかが分からず、試せません・・・

Comment: standalone.sh等のshellを使っている場合は standalone.sh -Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true でできるとおもいます。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます、大変助かりました。回答承認いたしますので、ぜひ回答での投稿をお願い致します。

Comment: 関連の質問（一番上に、この質問、と書いてあるやつ）に回答いただければ、報酬の信用度100点をさしあげられます。期限が後１時間しかないのでご注意ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。また、この質問であるように、設定ファイルからできるか試してもらいたいです。connectionURLにdefaultNChar=trueを含めるとどうなるんでしょうか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74610/discussion-between-daichi-itokazu-and-mok2pok)しましょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQLやH2などのDBを使用している場合、Standalone.xmlのconnection-urlにパラメタを設定することで可能だと思います。(下記はmysqlの例)

```
<datasource ...>
  <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</connection-url>
   .....
</datasource>
```

また、[こちらの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40133/nchar2-nvarchar2%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AB%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8C%96%E3%81%91%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E6%A0%BC%E7%B4%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)にもしましたが、oracleの場合、standalone.sh等の起動パラメタで

> -Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true

をつけることでNCharを使うことができるようです。
Oracleの場合connection-urlで設定可能かどうかは環境がないため試せないですが、しっかり動くようです。

[Wildfly 10 datasource configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration)

Comment: その書式はDBの種類に関わらず有効なのでしょうか？　それともMySQL専用でしょうか？`jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.100:1521:TEST?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8`のように書いてみましたが、エラー`WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid`が発生します。

Comment: Mysqlのオプションです。 :(

Comment: oracleの情報を回答に追加しました。